# Reduce size of project folder in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

Any thoughts on how to reduce the size of my project folder for my solution for an Xamarin Solution?

Thanks.

Comment: delete the bin and obj folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jason.  To expand on @Jason answer.

Here's the batch file I wrote to automate this for backup purposes:

```
@echo off
ECHO GET CURRENT DAY IN YYYYMMDD FORMAT
set CURRENT_DATE=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
echo %CURRENT_DATE%

ECHO DELETE BIN / OBJ FOLDERS
RMDIR C:\[PROJECT SOULTION]\bin /s /q
RMDIR C:\[PROJECT SOULTION]\obj /s /q
RMDIR C:\[PROJECT SOULTION].Android\bin /s /q
RMDIR C:\[PROJECT SOULTION].Android\obj /s /q
RMDIR C:\[PROJECT SOULTION].UWP\bin /s /q
RMDIR C:\[PROJECT SOULTION].UWP\obj /s /q

ECHO CREATE NEW VERSIONED BACKUP
XCOPY C:\[PROJECT SOULTION]  C:\[PROJECT SOULTION]\BACKUP\%CURRENT_DATE%\ /E /D /C /Y /H /I

Timeout /t 3
```